# Is it possible to fork a symlink?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, software-rec, ext4

I have my configuration file (e.g. .zshrc) put into an encfs container. When I log into the system the container is not yet mounted, hence the the symlink is dangling then. Is there a way to let the symlink to point to two locations, so if one is not present it uses the other?

Comment: That isn't possible AFAIK, but you could set it to the "default" location on login and start a background job that waits for the `encfs` container to become available, then overwrite the symlink and exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, but there's an alternative way to achieve the same effect (`sh` syntax; should work in `zsh` as well):

```
if ! find -L /dir/of/file -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type l -name filename
then
    . /dir/of/file/filename
    break # Or exit, return or whatever is necessary to avoid processing the rest of the file
fi
```

In other words, if the symlink is not broken, use that, otherwise continue in this file.